# role of the |> operator vs partial application

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code:

```
type transaction = Withdraw of int | Deposit of int | Checkbalance

(* Bank account generator. *)
let make_account(opening_balance: int) =
    let balance = ref opening_balance in
    fun (t: transaction) ->
      match t with
        | Withdraw(m) ->  if (!balance > m)
                          then
                            ((balance := !balance - m);
                            (Printf.printf "Balance is %i" !balance))
                          else
                            print_string "Insufficient funds."
        | Deposit(m) ->
           ((balance := !balance + m);
            (Printf.printf "Balance is %i\n" !balance)) 
        | Checkbalance -> (Printf.printf "Balance is %i\n" !balance)
;;
```

whenever I try to run the following command: `make_account(100) Deposit(50) ;;` I get the following error: This function has type int -> transaction -> unit. It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.

However the following command works just fine `Deposit(50) |> make_account(100) ;;`

But why aren't these two line of codes equivalent? shouldn't (make_account 100) be replaced by (fun (t: transaction) -> ...) ? Because then I don't understand why my first attempt did not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that Ocaml doesn't use parenthesis for function calls. In the statement

```
make_account (100) Deposit (50);;
```

you have two unnecessary grouping parenthesis, it is the same as

```
make_account  100  Deposit  50 ;;
```

where `make_account` is applied with three arguments. What you meant to write was

```
make_account 100 (Deposit 50);;
```

which is equivalent to the parenthesis-less

```
Deposit 50 |> make_account 100;;
```

Comment: absolutely! thank you. Then the role of the () around (Deposit 50) is to group it as a separate expression so ocaml can interpret it as the argument of the function returned by make account right?

Comment: @JosephhansBouAssaf Yes, exactly.

Comment: Or, using `@@`:  `make_account 100 @@ Deposit 50`